# What is the mysql query to get row which column has two specified values (4 , 7)?

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc

I need to query a table for rows which state column has the value "4" and "7"

info:

```
select count(def.Defect_id) from defects def where def.State = 4
select count(def.Defect_id) from defects def where def.State = 7
```

Here how can i find the no of defect_id(not primary key) rows which have records for state "4" and "7"

**(i need count of defect_id with state 4 and it should also exist in state 7)**

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT count(tbl1.defect_id) 
    FROM defects tbl1 INNER JOIN defects tbl2 on tbl1.defect_id = tbl2.defect_id
    WHERE tbl1.State = 4 AND tbl2.State = 7
```

Comment: That might be incorrect, they specifically mentioned `AND`. This is `OR`

Comment: I think it is hidden between the lines: `how can i find the number of defect_id rows which have records for state "4" and "7"`

Comment: it is not OR... i am looking for the defect_id which has both the states

Comment: @Ulfric Stormcloak Yes, what you just quoted says `and`, but your solution is `or`

Comment: i have arround 90k+ records in the table is there any way to speed this query.. it takes more time to execute (142sec) even in amazon Ec2

Comment: I think what I did is faster. In fact this is the only way. If you want to make it faster you have to modify your table. Make it normalize up to 4NF at least.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve **separate counts** for id `4` and `7` in one go as follows:

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN defect_id = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt4, 
       sum(CASE WHEN defect_id = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt7,
FROM defects
```

**UPDATE1**: It looks like question was understood differently.

This should work, but *only* as long as no more than one `state` exists per `defect_id` in your `defects` table:

```
SELECT count(d1.*)
FROM defects d1, defects d2
WHERE d1.defect_id = d2.defect_id
  AND d1.state = 4
  AND d2.state = 7
```

**UPDATE2**: If you can have more that one identical combination of `(defect_id, state)` in your table and want to count it only *once* for purposes of your id `4` and `7`, simply add `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
SELECT count(d1.defect_id)
FROM defects d1, defects d2
WHERE d1.defect_id = d2.defect_id
  AND d1.state = 4
  AND d2.state = 7
GROUP BY
   d1.defect_id,
   d1.state,
   d2.state
```

Comment: but my answer is a lot shorter and easier.:)

Comment: But this gives *separate* counts, which is more detail and may be needed by business logic. Adding up will lose that info

Comment: And this answers what the OP asked, the other solution will return incorrect numbers since that works on an `OR` logic and OP just clearly mentioned again that they need to find data which has Both states

Comment: i need count of defect_id with state 4 should also exist in state 7

Comment: does it mean that `defect_id` is NOT primary key?

Comment: If you want to make it faster, be sure to have multi-column index for `(defect_id, state)`. You can drop existing index on `(defect_id)` and create one on `(defect_id, state)` - this index will still work just as fast for searches only on `defect_id`, but it will speedup this query immensely.